# Not Showing Error,but it should while using .val() method in wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function preparetobefilledData()
{
    if(checkForNullValue($('#BeforeAfterSelect'))==false &&     checkForNullValue($('#feedbackDays')))
    {
        if($('#BeforeAfterSelect').val()==1)
    {
        $('#EXIT_SETUP_WHEN').val()=(-1)*($('#feedbackDays').val());//line 1
    }
    else if($('#BeforeAfterSelect')==2)
    {
        $('#EXIT_SETUP_WHEN').val()=$('#feedbackDays').val();//line 2
    }   
}
if(checkForNullValue($('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUI'))==false)
{
    $('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUIRED').val()=$('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUI').val();//line 3
}
```

}

I wrote the above function.while executing ,firebug showing invalid assingnment on left hend side on line 3,but shouldn't it also show/generate error on line 2 and 1.

Only difference in b/w assignments is that //line 3 assings 'string' as a variable value while 2 and 1 assings Digits as variable value.

What is the difference b/w assignment of these 2 while using jquery .val() mehtod.
Why I have to use this---> obj.val('value to be assigned'),only in last case.

Comment: check out val() api cal first.http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I guess your script never reaches the invalid lines. Notice, that `Invalid assingnment on left hand side` is a runtime error, it can't be detected at parsing time.

Comment: @ArunChandranC I know I have written wrong code,my qus actually was ,why I was not getting error on those lines. :) HUgo S. Mendes and Teemu have given a valid reason.

Comment: @Rishi I guess you got answer any way javascript is have sequential execution once it throw an error from any line it will skip the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the object `$('#EXIT_SETUP_WHEN')` and this is the val `$('#EXIT_SETUP_WHEN').val()` you need to adjust your code using the correct statement.

The line 3 is out of the function...Hence.. it is being called first... and, so, throwing the exception.

to adjust the line 3 you will need to change this:

`$('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUIRED').val()=$('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUI').val();`

to this:

`$('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUIRED').val($('#EXIT_SETUP_REQUI').val());`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u need. You are assigning Value to the `jquery` `object` when you want to set value of that object

```
$('#EXIT_SETUP_WHEN').val((-1)*($('#feedbackDays').val()));
```

Comment: yes,But why don't I need this in first 2 cases.There too I am doing assignment. {.val() is present is all three lines,edited}

Comment: You have again done it wrong . its $('#EXIT_SETUP_WHEN').val("value")